# Is there a transitive verb akin to "launch" that means "to make a plane take off"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

We can say "We launched the rocket." We can say "We made the plane take off." Can we say "We launched the plane?" If not, is there an acceptable way to say it using a transitive verb like "launch"?

Comment: If no one can think of such a word, I'd love to hear speculation as to why there isn't one.

Comment: Is this from an airport or an aircraft carrier?

Comment: Good question. Aircraft carriers launch, and their aircraft are launched; definitely an active transitive verb. Pilots could use almost any verb to mean _cause to take off_, but most English causative verbs are identical to their corresponding inchoative verb, like _The bowl filled with water/He filled the bowl with water_. There far fewer special pairs that are different, like _die_ and _kill_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any *transitive* verbs to fit this context, but there are many *intransitive* ones.

**"Take off," "lift off," "depart," "become airborne," "take to the air,"** and **"ascend"** are all intransitive verbs that you could use to describe "launching" a plane.

"Take off" — (of an aircraft or bird) become airborne. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/take_off)]

"Lift off" — (of an aircraft, spacecraft, or rocket) rise from the ground or a launch pad, especially vertically. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/lift_off)]

"Depart" — Leave, especially in order to start a journey. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/depart)]

"Airborne" is defined as: (of an aircraft) in the air after taking off. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/airborne)]
Therefore, "become airborne" — is similar to "to take off into the air."

"Take to the air" — To begin to fly. [[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/take-to-the-air)]

"Ascend" — Rise through the air. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ascend)]